# Using NSZombieEnabled for debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS with the Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, memory-management

I am debugging with NSZombieEnabled variable for my executable which is crashing on the device but it is not crashing on the simulator. How do I solve this hitch when I am debugging with the iPhone device.

```
2011-01-14 13:53:08.948 AppName[179:307] 

*** -[ReaderViewController setOriginalNavigatorURL:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3caa8d0
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

(gdb) info malloc_history 0x3caa8d0
Undefined info command: "malloc_history 0x3caa8d0".  Try "help info".
```

(gdb) What to type here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [these instructions to run Instruments with Zombies](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/) so that you can view the allocation history, etc.

Comment: ObjAllocations instrument: ‘Enable NSZombie’ Detection and ‘Record Reference Counts’ only work with the Simulator.

Comment: How about overriding -release, -retain and -autorelease to NSLog or break in GDB whenever you get called? This could give you the same info. You could also log a stack trace at that point.